# Erlang string to atom and formatting a string

Tags: erlang

Using just `list_to_atom()` gives:

```
list_to_atom("hello"). 
hello
list_to_atom("Hello").
'Hello'
```

why the difference?

I am trying to format a string with numbers, strings and atoms as follows:

```
lists:flatten(io_lib:format("PUTVALUE ~p ~p", [list_to_atom("hello"), 40])).
"PUTVALUE hello 40"
lists:flatten(io_lib:format("PUTVALUE ~p ~p", [list_to_atom("Hello"), 40])).
"PUTVALUE 'Hello' 40"
```

what is the best way of doing this in Erlang?

**Edit:** To make the question clear, there are more values than the example above and in some cases the value can be a string or an atom, like

```
lists:flatten(io_lib:format("PUTVALUE ~p ~p ~p", [list_to_atom("hello"), X, 40])).
```

where the first parameter is always a string but `X` can either be an atom or a string. The third parameter is always a number.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to get a flat list for strings and integers, using `~s` and `~B` may be straitforward:

```
lists:flatten(io_lib:format("PUTVALUE ~s ~B", ["Hello", 40])).
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. what if one of the parameters can be a string or an atom?

Comment: atoms are formatted by either `~s` or `~p`. By `~s`, results are not quoted by single quote characters. See http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-1 for complete reference.

Answer (score 13):

In Erlang, an atom starts with a lowercase letter. For an atom to starts with an uppercase letter, it must be enclosed with single quotes.

http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id66663

Answer (score 6):

You can use lists:concat for formatting such string

```
 lists:concat(["PUTVALUE ",hello," ",40]).
```

Answer (score -1):

Erlang atoms always must start with a lower-case letter. That's why it is giving you a different result when you try to create an atom with the initial capital letter. It's creating an atom by adding the ' quotes because of the capital H.

Comment: This was given as an answer a decade ago.

Comment: True, but other, less correct, answers were voted higher. I guess I should have just upvoted it.